# matplotlib y-axis label on right side

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

Is there a simple way to put the y-axis label on the right-hand side of the plot? I know that this can be done for the tick labels using `ax.yaxis.tick_right()`, but I would like to know if it can be done for the axis label as well.

One idea which came to mind was to use

```
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel('foo')
```

However, this doesn't have the desired effect of placing all labels (tick and axis labels) on the right-hand side, while preserving the extent of the y-axis. In short, I would like a way to move all the y-axis labels from the left to the right.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

It looks like you can do it with:

```
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
```

See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120618121009/http://notes.brooks.nu/2008/03/plotting-on-left-and-right-axis-simulateously-using-matplotlib-and-numpy) for an example.

Comment: if you try to place the labels inside/on the plotarea see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47874059/4933053

Comment: It works only for the legend, not the figures of the axis. Do you have an idea to solve this problem ?

Comment: Is there a single command which would do both of these in Matplotlib or is it just unnecessarily verbose?

Comment: @ifly6 Not sure if there is one inbuilt, I do this: `rhs = lambda ax: (ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right"), ax.yaxis.tick_right())`

Comment: If you want to see the labels other way around, use `rotation` parameter with 270 degrees: `ax.set_ylabel("Label", rotation=270)`

Answer (score 28):

If you would like to follow the example given in `matplotlib` and create a figure with labels on both sides of the axes but without having to use the `subplots()` function, here is my solution :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

ax1 = plt.plot()
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
plt.plot(t,s1,'b-')
plt.xlabel('t (s)')
plt.ylabel('exp',color='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r.')
plt.ylabel('sin', color='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me:   
    `File "prueba.py", line 11, in <module>`
    `ax2 = ax1.twinx()`
    `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'twinx'`

Comment: try plt.gca().twinx()

Comment: try `ax1 = plt.subplot()`

Answer (score 11):

The previous answers are out of date. Here is the most recent code for the example above:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
data1 = np.exp(t)
data2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

From [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-two-scales-py).

Answer (score 7):

(sorry for resurrecting the question)

I know it's a dirty trick, but if you don't want to go down to axes handling and stay in `plt`commands, you can use the `labelpad` scalar argument to position your label to the right of the graph side. Works after a bit of trial and error, and the exact scalar value possibly (?) has to do with the dimensions of your figure size.

Example:

```
# move ticks
plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='both', labelleft=False, labelright=True)

# move label
plt.ylabel('Your label here', labelpad=-725, fontsize=18)
```