# Matplotlib move tick labels inside plot area

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to put tick labels inside the plotting area?  I have already tried:

```
ax.tick_params(axis="y",pad=-.5, left="off",labelleft="on")
```

and

```
ax.tick_params(axis="y",direction="in", left="off",labelleft="on")
```

The former just moves the axis inward, and the latter only moves the ticks not the tick labels.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I guess you are completely on the right track. The problem is just to find the good parameters for the padding in order to have the ticklabels inside the axes. The padding is measured in points, so it makes sense to use much larger numbers than 0.5. Also the padding is different for x and y axis due to the text's alignment.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.tick_params(axis="y",direction="in", pad=-22)
ax.tick_params(axis="x",direction="in", pad=-15)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to let the plot take consider of the size of the tick labels. For example, as we increase their size, the rectangular become smaller, like standardize it.

Comment: @steven : You can use `horizontalalignment` instead (for y-tick-labels), i.e. `ha='left'` which voids the need for `pad`. I also prefer to set `va='top'` to move the labels underneath grid lines.

Answer (score 6):

## Update

I completely forgot about the `pad` param in `tick_params`.  [@ImportanceOfBeingErnest’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47874059/6028742) makes use of this and is more appropriate for the question asked.

Nevertheless, I will leave my answer here as an example of how one could achieve the same goal if it weren’t available through a general method like `thick_params`.

---

<strike>I am not aware of the official way to achieve this. But you can *hard code* it.</strike>

If you want to have the ticks only on the inside, you only need to run:

```
ax.tick_params(direction="in")
```

Now, to move the labels inside the plot area, you need to add padding to the ticks, as follows:

```
TICK_PADDING = -10

xticks = [*ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks(), *ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks()]
yticks = [*ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks(), *ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks()]

for tick in (*xticks, *yticks):
        tick.set_pad(TICK_PADDING)
```

You might have to use different padding for the x and y ticks.  In which case you should:

```
X_TICK_PADDING = -10
Y_TICK_PADDING = -20

xticks = [*ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks(), *ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks()]
yticks = [*ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks(), *ax.yaxis.get_minor_ticks()]

for tick in xticks:
    tick.set_pad(X_TICK_PADDING)

for tick in yticks:
    tick.set_pad(Y_TICK_PADDING)
```

It's not pretty but it works. <strike>Let me know if this is what you wanted.</strike>

Comment: This is doing the exact same as the other answer, just with a lot more code lines. Can you comment on why this would be preferable over using `tick_params` only?

Comment: I missed the `pad` param in `tick_params`. I think the method in your answer is better than mine. Now I’m wondering why yours has been downvoted and mine upvoted...?

Comment: I guess my answer was downvoted because somebody wanted to downvote just any answer of mine; around the same time I received two other downvotes on other questions, which are also perfectly fine. So nothing to wory about.

Comment: but these methods are not generic in nature. can these padding be applied to any plots? why padding has to be set initially as -10 or -20.. cant's these be computed from the axis reference (e.g. x=0) and then place the label values appropriately?

Comment: @tpvasconcelos depending on the use-case, this one might be preferred because it is more adjustable. I used this one since my labels consist of texts of different lengths so I could set the padding for each tick individually, which is not possible with the other solution. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: It does not work for radar/polar charts.