# how to put tick mark on the box from outside to inside in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

```py
x_axis = list(df.columns)[0]                      
y_axis = list(df.columns)[4]                      

x_axis_wo_unit = parameters_wo_unit[0]                      
y_axis_wo_unit = parameters_wo_unit[1]                      

x_axis_wo_unit = batch_parameter_type_wo_unit             


df.plot(x= x_axis,y= y_axis)
plt.xscale("log")

plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eX5qr.png)

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873389/matplotlib-move-tick-labels-inside-plot-area

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib move tick labels inside plot area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873389/matplotlib-move-tick-labels-inside-plot-area)