# Matplotlib ticks inside the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to move the ticks inside the plots in matplotlib (I use subplots).

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47873389/matplotlib-move-tick-labels-inside-plot-area/47874059#47874059) and I tried the following code:

```
axes.tick_params(axis="y",direction="in")
axes.tick_params(axis="x",direction="in")
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tick_params'
```

After that, I found [this webpage](https://www-python--simple-com.translate.goog/python-matplotlib/configuration-axes.php?_x_tr_sch=http&_x_tr_sl=fr&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp) on matplotlib axes configuration (Original page in French [here](http://www.python-simple.com/python-matplotlib/configuration-axes.php)).

So, I tried to use the `pyplot.gca()` command as follow:

```
gca().xaxis.set_tick_params(direction = 'in')

gca().yaxis.set_tick_params(direction = 'in')
```

It worked but not totally.

As you can see, on the X axis, only the first tick is inside the plot. On the Y axis, only the last subplot has a tick inside the plot. Moreover, the "subticks" between 1 and 10 are outside the plot (I have to use a log scale)...

[image: Plot]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.pyplot import show, subplots, gca


# This part of code works 

#####################################################################################


# Definition of the dataframe

df = pd.DataFrame({'Colors': {0: 'Red', 1: 'Blue', 2: 'Green', 3: 'Blue', 4: 'Red'}, 'X_values': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'Y_values': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 8, 3: 10, 4: 4}, 'MinY_values': {0: 1.5, 1: 3, 2: 7.5, 3: 8, 4: 2}, 'MaxY_values': {0: 2.5, 1: 5, 2: 9.5, 3: 11, 4: 6}})


# Definition of the different colors and labels

color = []

labels = []
 

for i in df['Colors']:
    if i == 'Red':
        color.append('red')
        labels.append('It is a red point')
    if i == 'Blue':
        color.append('blue')
        labels.append('What a wonderful blue point')
    if i == 'Green':
        color.append('green')
        labels.append('Sounds to be a green point')
 
# Figure

fig,axes = subplots(3,1,sharex = True)

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.975,
bottom=0.07,
left=0.05,
right=0.585,
hspace=0.0,
wspace=0.2) 

for x_val,y_val,min_val,max_val,colors in zip(df['X_values'],df['Y_values'],df['MinY_values'],df['MaxY_values'],color):
    axes[0].errorbar(x_val,y_val,yerr = [[min_val],[max_val]] ,color = colors,barsabove='True',fmt = 'o')

axes[0].axhline(y=5, color='black', linestyle='--')

axes[0].set_xscale("log")
axes[0].set_yscale("log")
    
for x_val,y_val,min_val,max_val,colors in zip(df['X_values'],df['Y_values'],df['MinY_values'],df['MaxY_values'],color):
    axes[1].errorbar(x_val,y_val,yerr = [[min_val],[max_val]] ,color = colors,barsabove='True',fmt = 'o')

axes[1].axhline(y=5, color='black', linestyle='--')

axes[1].set_xscale("log")
axes[1].set_yscale("log")
    
for x_val,y_val,min_val,max_val,colors in zip(df['X_values'],df['Y_values'],df['MinY_values'],df['MaxY_values'],color):
    axes[2].errorbar(x_val,y_val,yerr = [[min_val],[max_val]] ,color = colors,barsabove='True',fmt = 'o',label = labels)

axes[2].set_xscale("log")
axes[2].set_yscale("log")

axes[2].axhline(y=5, color='black', linestyle='--')

#######################################################################################################

# I need help here

# Ticks

# axes.tick_params(axis="y",direction="in")
# axes.tick_params(axis="x",direction="in")

gca().xaxis.set_tick_params(direction = 'in')

gca().yaxis.set_tick_params(direction = 'in')


show()
```

Comment: You need to call it for every individual `ax`, and also for both minor and major ticks. E.g. `for ax in axes: ax.tick_params(axis="both", which="both", direction="in")`

Comment: It works, thank you. By doing this, I don't have the attribute error.

Comment: `axes` is a numpy array with 3 elements. Each element is an `ax`. You can't call matplotlib functions on that numpy array, only on the individual elements.