# Pyplot title vertical position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like the title of my plot to be within the plot. With [`plt.title`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html), I can only adjust left/right/center and I can't set vertical position. I am also using a legend, so using `plt.legend` as a workaround to setting the position of the title doesn't work. How can I get `title` to set the title inside the plot rather than above?

---

"Default" is where `plt.title` sets the title. "Title" is where I would like the title to be.

[image: Example figure]

I want the vertical position of the title to be just under the top of the plot regardless of plot resizing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like `plt.title("Title", y=0.9)`?

Comment: I didn't know about that option, but when I resize the plot, the title changes place. I would like something that acts like `title`, but where the title sits right under the top of the plot rather than right above.

Answer (score 0):

From this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369888/matplotlib-y-axis-label-on-right-side):

```
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.yaxis.tick_right()
```

If you're dealing with images, and just want to show the title image horizontally on the right, you need to **remove ticks**

```
ax.set_ylabel("image\nlong\ntitle", fontsize=10)
ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
ax.tick_params(axis='y')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```