# python matplotlib: I need to change the xlabel postion from left tu right

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure, subplot, axes

I want to change the ylabel default postion:

`plt.ylabel("NEW Ylabel", fontsize = 8)  # loc = "right"`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib y-axis label on right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369888/matplotlib-y-axis-label-on-right-side)

Comment: More or less, thanks